# How to change editor of K2 Joomla 'extra fields'?

Tags: joomla, editor, joomla-k2

Is it possible to change the editor used when inputting data in 'extra fields' in the K2 content component for Joomla?

When pasting large swathes of content from MS Word, clicking 'Save', then re-opening the article, the data is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, just not through configuration parameters. I edited the 'extraFields' view `(admin -> components -> com_k2 -> views -> extraField -> view.html.php)` and added a Javascript include to load a different editor.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to change the editor. And why do you want to change the editor? What is that you are trying to input?